# Root shows 100% used but drive is not full

Tags: mount

My drive appears to be full but it doesn't look right. I am showing a 30G drive with 3.1G used and nothing available. Any ideas on what could cause this?

```
/var/log# df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       30G  3.1G     0 100% /
none            512M  4.0K  512M   1% /dev
none            103M  1.1M  102M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            512M     0  512M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Comment: You don't have a real file system (it's simfs - simulated) and whilst you still have quota available, your host system has run out of resources so none are available for that directory (which is your / simfs even though you do have quota remaining).  You may need to take this up with your host-provider

Comment: Duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/714219/linux-says-my-space-is-full-with-2-4-50gb-used

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using VPS, quick search on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=dev%20simfs) shows it. This is quote from answer on [https://serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/714260)

> You're using an OpenVZ-based VPS, and on this VPS your root filesystem
>   isn't really a filesystem, but [a directory on the host](http://anonexp.blogspot.com/2013/01/simfs-openvz-container-filesystem.html). That
>   directory on the host has run out of disk space.
>
> This is a strong sign that your provider has significantly
>   overcommitted resources and isn't monitoring them well, or at all. The
>   [replacement for simfs, known as ploop](http://openvz.livejournal.com/40830.html), is more difficult to
>   overcommit, has a stronger guarantee of disk space, and performs
>   better.
>
> I would strongly advise you to find another provider as soon as
>   possible. This is very unlikely to be the last problem you will have
>   with your current one. (And, of course, one not based on OpenVZ.)

<sub>By [@Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton)</sub>

Comment: Thanks everyone. You hit the nail on the head. I searched google but must have used the wrong keywords. Didn't even think about it being a host issue with my VPS.